# Calculate match index of regexp

Tags: python, regex

I have a txt file f, which contains specific tagged spans in-between the `<a>` and `</a>` tags.

For example:

```
<a>George</a> and his <a>friends</a>, came back <a>home</a>.
```

I match these using re's `finditer`, but I would like to be able to calculate their indexes if the tags were not part of the text.

For example if: George and his friends, came back home.

What I did was

```
import re
text = "<a>George</a> and his <a>friends</a>, came back <a>home</a>"
tags = re.finditer('(?<=<a>).*?(?=</a>)',f)
```

to get the tags and the start and end of the span, and then

```
opening = re.finditer(r"<a>", f)
opening = [(i.group(0), i.start(), i.end()) for i in opening]

closing = re.finditer(r"</a>", f)
closing = [(i.group(0), i.start(), i.end()) for i in closing]
```

to also obtain the indexes of the opening and closing tags of the spans.

How could I go about calculating the indexes of the spans if the tags were not part of the text? I initially thought of subtracting -3 from the start and end of the span respectively, but for the next span, that would not work since I would need to subtract -3 + the distance between the closing tag and the opening tag (I think).

I cannot get the spans and then look for them in a "clean" text, because their position is specific, and I do not want to match multiple occurrences of the same word.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you really trying to accomplish by getting these indexes?

Comment: I want to, having the offsets and the span text, align the text with the spans as in https://www.lighttag.io/blog/sequence-labeling-with-transformers/example

I cannot change the format of the initial texts I get, I would just like to modify them so that they fit my needs. But I get stuck in the math of the transformation of the text and what that means for the offsets

Comment: Given the input `<a>George</a> and his <a>friends</a>, came back <a>home</a>.` - what should be the output?

Comment: [(George, 0, 5), (friends, 15, 21), (home, 34, 37)]

Answer (score 1):

Count the number of tags processed and subtract the lengths accordingly.

```
import re
text = "<a>George</a> and his <a>friends</a>, came back <a>home</a>"
tags = re.finditer('(?<=<a>).*?(?=</a>)',text)

num_tags = 0
results = []
for tag in tags:
    start_idx = tag.start() - 7*num_tags - 3 
    end_idx = tag.end() - 7*num_tags - 4
    num_tags += 1
    results.append((tag.group(0),start_idx, end_idx))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to hold the running offset from the start/end positions returned by the regexp, incrementing it by 7 for each match.

```
text = "<a>George</a> and his <a>friends</a>, came back <a>home</a>"
offset = 0
tags = []
for match in re.finditer('(?<=<a>).*?(?=</a>)',text):
    start = match.start() - 3 - offset
    end = match.end() - 3 - offset
    offset += 7
    tags.append((match.group(0), start, end))
```

Comment: The end index is incorrect. It should be `end = match.end() - 4 - offset` instead of `end = match.end() - 3 - offset` as `</a>` is of length 4.

Comment: @EshwarSR But `match.end()` is the position of the beginning of `</a>`, not the end, so we don't need to subtract its length.

Comment: The length of `</a>` is included in the 7 increment.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, yes it is the start of `</a>`, hence it is the index of `<` in `</a>` hence we need to subtract 4 instead of 3. Try executing your code, you will see the end index is one greater than expected.

Comment: It's the index *after* the match, not the index of the last character in the match.

Comment: `match.end()` is consistent with the way Python uses indexes in slices.

Comment: Yes, exactly, that's the point. The `match.end()` corresponds to the index of `<` in `</a>`.  Please run your code and check the output. The author of the question wants the end index of the tag, not the python way of indices in slices.

Comment: My point is that this is deliberate. The size of the field is `end-start`. The author's desire is wrong, since it's not as useful when slicing or determining field widths.